# Insert long html code in javascript, but onclick doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am using `innerHTML` to insert long `html` code to `javascript`.

Here is an example similar to my example:

```js
    let result = document.getElementById('result')
    function display(){
        result.innerHTML += '<input id="searchterm" type="text" /> <input id="search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchdata()"></input>'
        function searchdata(){
            console.log('it works')
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick='display()'>Display</button>
<div id=result></div>
```

The problem is when I run click the `search button`, it will display `Uncaught ReferenceError: searchdata is not defined`.

I know if I declare the `function` before I do the `innerHTML` statement, this will absolutely work.

However, I just wonder why does this happens?

Also, could someone provide me a better way to insert `html` in `javascript` because I want to insert a whole `form` in `javascript`(which is much more than I show in the example) and by using `innerHTML`, it is pretty hard to change and find bug later?

Thanks for any responds!

Updated: **I know how to fix the problem, but I just looking for the reason and an advanced way of inserting `html` in `javascript`**

Comment: you need move the `searchdata` function outside to global scope, not inside `display`

Comment: Why did you say "The problem is when I run click the search button, it will display Uncaught ReferenceError: searchdata is not defined" And then say "I know how to fix the problem, but I just looking for the reason and an advanced way of inserting html in javascript"? You are telling us 2 different problems back and fourth, what IS the problem?

Comment: @ParkingMaster, what I mean is that I just wonder why does this display error and just wonder is there an advanced way of solving it?

Comment: @Yusuf I edited edited NiyaziBabayev's answer and provided information on the topic.

Comment: @ParkingMaster firstly thanks for your help, but are you sure you edit the answer? I don't see any edits?

Comment: @Yusuf It hasn't been aproved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving "searchdata()" function out of the local scope and call it inside "display()" function. See if it works like this.

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result')

function searchdata() {
  console.log('it works')
}

function display() {
  result.innerHTML += '<input id="searchterm" type="text" /> <input id="search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchdata()"></input>'
  searchdata();
}
```